# Adding static text to an unordered list

Tags: html, href, html-lists

I would like to add some static text to an unordered list so that text aligns with the baseline of the list items. e.g. Page 1 2 3  where Page is the static element and 1,2,3 are the active list items. I tried creating them separately however there is an alignment problem when viewed in IE 7.

```
<div class="headB" id="page">Page</div>
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="pageNum" -->
<div class="headB" id="pageNum">
<ul> 
     <li><a href="../message3.html">3</a></li>
     <li><a href="../message2.html">2</a></li>
     <li><a href="../message1.html">1</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I've revised code so that its contained in 1 div, however IE 7 places the word Page between the 1 and 2

```
<div class="headB" id="pageNum">
<ul>
   <li><a href="../consumer1.html">2</a></li>
<li><a href="../consumer2.html">1</a></li>
<span class="headB">Page</span>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I've revised code so that its contained in 1 div, however IE 7 places the word Page between the 1 and 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a better idea to move your `<span>` outside the `<ul>`. You are not supposed to put `span` inside `ul`, see [html lists](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp).

```
<div class="headB" id="pageNum">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="../consumer1.html">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="../consumer2.html">1</a></li>
  </ul>
  <span class="headB">Page</span>
</div>
```

This way, the `span` appears after the list on a newline in all browsers (including IE7).
If you want to align it with the list, use some additional CSS.
[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/HKckN/2/)

Comment: Thank you – what would be the most effective way to style this for IE 7? Should the .headB be text align left or float left?